# Maven deps do not find version fields in POM

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project which, following a restart, has had a peculiar issue: it reports that there is no version field for one of the dependencies (apache-camel), even though the field is in fact populated. I have checked the pom.xml source, and confirmed that the field is in fact there and populated for all the dependencies. I am uncertain why m2e is saying otherwise. Is this a known issue, and if so, is there a specific fix for it?

The version of the m2e plugin is 1.5.1, and this is the parent POM for the project. Here is the dependencies section of POM file in question:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-camel</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-parent</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
        <artifactId>mina-parent</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with m2e saying that the version field was not present.

In my case the version field was not the problem. Actually the problem was, that the dependency was defined twice.

Have you checked if the apache-camel or any other dependency (maybe also from a parent pom) is defined twice?

Comment: I don't see how; it is the only POM in the project not imported by the POM itself.

Comment: I found the source of the problem: one of the other dependencies, Apache MINA, was itself requiring Camel as a sub-dependency. Removing the explicit apache-camel dependency solved the issue. Thank you for your advice